# Unexpected mismatch between local and server runs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eclipse, jsp, azure

I have created an eshop and when I run the project locally at Eclipse the script that I attach below executes when a user click the button **Order Now**. After this the cart Item has at least 1 product.

I have uploaded the project at Azure and the action of the button **Order Now** does not work properly.

**viewProduct.jsp**

```
<!-- Import spring text -->
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp"%>


<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Product Detail</h1>

            <p class="lead">Here is the detail information of the product</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Grid system from Bootstrap -->
        <div class="container" ng-app="cartApp">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img
                        src="<c:url value="/resources/images/${product.productId}.png" /> "
                        alt="image" style="width: 100%" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <h3>${product.productName}</h3>
                    <p>${product.productDescription}</p>
                    <p>
                        <strong>Manufacture</strong> : ${product.productManufacture}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <strong>Category</strong> : ${product.productCategory}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <strong>Condition</strong> : ${product.productCondition}
                    </p>
                    <p>${product.productPrice}USD</p>

                    <br>

                    <c:set var="role" scope="page" value="${param.role}" />
                    <c:set var="url" scope="page" value="/product/productList" />
                    <!-- if the user is admin we change the back page for the following "back" button -->
                    <c:if test="${role='admin'}">
                        <c:set var="url" scope="page" value="/admin/productInventory" />
                    </c:if>

                    <p ng-controller="cartCtrl">
                        <a href="<c:url value="${url}" />" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
                        <!-- we use the angular funtction (#)  -->
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-large"
                            ng-click="addToCart('${product.productId}')"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Order Now</a>

                        <a href="<spring:url value="/customer/cart" />" class="btn btn-default"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>View Cart</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/controller.js" /> "></script>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp"%>
```

At **cart.jsp** file I also try to execute clearCart() from controller.js. Also the code does not run.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp" %>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/controller.js" /> "></script>

<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Cart</h1>

                    <p>All the selected products in your shopping cart</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="container" ng-app="cartApp">
            <div ng-controller = "cartCtrl" ng-init="initCartId('${cartId}')">
            <div>
                <a class="btn btn-danger pull-left" ng-click="clearCart()"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>Clear Cart</a>
                <a href="<spring:url value="/order/${cartId}"/>"
                   class="btn btn-success pull-right"><span class="glyphicon-shopping-cart glyphicon"></span> Check out
                </a>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat = "item in cart.cartItems">
                    <td>{{item.product.productName}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.product.productPrice}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.totalPrice}}</td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="label label-danger" ng-click="removeFromCart(item.product.productId)">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>remove</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Grand Total</th>
                    <th>{{calGrandTotal()}}</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <a href="<spring:url value="/" />" class="btn btn-default">Continue Shopping</a>
            </div>
        </section>

    </div>
</div>


<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp" %>
```

**controller.js**

```
var cartApp = angular.module ("cartApp", []);

cartApp.controller("cartCtrl", function ($scope, $http){

    $scope.refreshCart = function () {
        $http.get('/eMusicStore/rest/cart/'+$scope.cartId).success(function (data) {
           $scope.cart=data;
        });
    };

    $scope.clearCart = function () {
        $http.delete('/eMusicStore/rest/cart/'+$scope.cartId).success($scope.refreshCart());
    };

    $scope.initCartId = function (cartId) {
        $scope.cartId = cartId;
        $scope.refreshCart(cartId);
    };

    $scope.addToCart = function (productId) {
        $http.put('/eMusicStore/rest/cart/add/'+productId).success(function () {
            alert("Product successfully added to the cart!")
        });
    };

    $scope.removeFromCart = function (productId) {
        $http.put('/eMusicStore/rest/cart/remove/'+productId).success(function (data) {
            $scope.refreshCart();
        });
    };

    $scope.calGrandTotal = function () {
        var grandTotal=0;

        for (var i=0; i<$scope.cart.cartItems.length; i++) {
            grandTotal+=$scope.cart.cartItems[i].totalPrice;
        }

        return grandTotal;
    };
});
```

Comment: What does _"does not work properly"_ mean? **How** exactly does it not work? Do you get any error messages (in server log, in browser console)?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek no errors. I click **Order Now** and the Angular code does not execute because the alert that I have in the **addToCart** function does not appear. So I think that angular code never executes.

Comment: Could you add an `alert` to the first line of **addToCart** function to check whether it has been called or not?

Comment: I realize that the problem is not only in the server. I have added alerts to all functions. When I am on **viewProduct.jsp** and I click **Order Now** the alert from controller.js executes. When I click Cart (to view the current products) I see the following  alerts:  from initCart, refreshCart, calGrandTotal, and after this the same alerts with the same sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code to log HTTP error response.

```
$http.put('/eMusicStore/rest/cart/remove/'+productId).success(function (data) {
    $scope.refreshCart();
}).error(function (data, status, header, config) {
    console.log(data);    
});
```

Comment: All this code is from e-course. But I think that there are some problems. I can see that in initCartId the refreshCart has an argument (cartId) but at the definition of refreshCart there is no argument! After this, function calGrandTotal does not have arguments. So how this function try to find the result of grandTotal? I would like to ask for nderstanding if something of what I say does not apply, but I am really junior in Angular.

Comment: After too many attempts (and going back some projects at the start of the creation of cart) the current errors are.
    **SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SpringMVC] in context with path [/eMusicStore] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError**

I have asked a week ago for this error. Someone gave me a link but I cannot find what's going wrong.